# How to avoid WordPress visitor access to wordpress/ folder instead of domain in Plesk after making that folder the site root?

Tags: domains, redirects, directory

I used Plesk and installed WordPress at `example.com/wordpress` 
After a while, I moved the access of my WordPress to root (`example.com`) 
But, instead of moving all files to the root directory (httpdocs/) I changed the domain folder reference to `httpdocs/wordpress`, So I don't need to move the WordPress installation to the root folder.

But, I wonder if this will cause problem. How do I prevent visitors visit `example.com/wordpress`?

Should I put a redirection via `.htaccess`? if so, would it be affect the accessibility of example.com (endless redirection)?